# How to Blacklist-bcm43.conf file from being automatically edited?

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I have a Dell Inspiron E1505 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I first installed the operating system, my broadcom wired network module wasn't recognized. I was able to troubleshoot that issue to the blacklist-bcm43 conf file and I commented out the "Blacklist b43 / Blacklist b43 Legacy / Blacklist b44" lines. This fixed the issue until today when, after updating the os, the lines became unhashed once again. I went in to fix it, but after about a minute of internet use, the lines became unhashed yet again. The only website I was trying to access was drive.google.com

Is there some way to prevent the system from editing the blacklist-bcm conf file, or use another work around to bypass the blacklist?

Also, I'm a bit of an Ubuntu novice (~1 year with the os, ~2 years with linux in general) so the more step-by-step the explanation, the better.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a web page doesn't change any system files. According to http://pastebin.com/P6MfyjdU that file is automatically regenerated by a wireless adapter configuration tool.

I also found an [article about conflicting drivers for your adapter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Broadcom_BCM4311_Natty_11.04). The lower section suggests

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Afterwards you will need to

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use WICD because it is a simple and easy to use network manager. Its a very good alternative to network manager in Ubuntu and it seems to always work when Network Manager doesn't. To install it just open up the terminal. Now download the latest NetworkManager, in case you need to reinstall it if WICD doesn't work

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Then to install it

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

And now you need to uninstall NetworkManager:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Now you can find WICD in your menu Start WICD, find the network you want to use and enter the information needed, password, encryption, etcetera and choose Automatically Connect to this network. You should be good to go!

WICD may also be available in Ubuntu Update Manager so you can look there first but it is important to uninstall Network Manager completely to prevent conflicts!!